# Javascript - Count same values and divide result of same values in array

Tags: javascript, console.log

How to use the division operation in the following code

here I use the condition if the array value 1 is red, 2 is white, and 3 is brown

because this is a sock, so if the value is even like 2 then it is counted as a pair (1).

```
const stok = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3];

function sockMerchant() {
    const colors = ["","red","white","brown"]; 
    const count = stok => stok.reduce((prev, curr) => (prev[curr] = ++prev[curr] || 1, prev), {}); 
    
    const strings = Object.entries(count(stok)).reduce((acc,[key,val]) => (acc[colors[key]] = val , acc),[]); 

    return strings;
    
}



console.log(sockMerchant(stok))
```

if there are the same values and the calculated value is even then it is divided by 2

my output

```
[red: 2, white: 2, brown: 4]
```

my expected output

```
[red: 1, white: 1, brown: 2]
```

**thank you in advance

Comment: do you really want an array with properties? have you tried to get the wanted result?

Comment: _"if there are the same values"_ - by that you mean, any of the numbers in `stok` existing more than one? _"and the calculated value is even then it is divided by 2"_ - and if not?

Comment: here I use the condition if the array value 1 is red, 2 is white, and 3 is brown

because this is a sock, so if the value is even like 2 then it is counted as a pair (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't get array with properties.**

So, I am creating an object having the requirements in the question.

```js
const stok = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3];

function sockMerchant() {
  const colors = ["red", "white", "brown"];
  const count = stok.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    prev[curr - 1]++; //add to the index in prev
    return prev;
  }, [...Array(colors.length)].fill(0));
  //take an array initially with the length of colors and value 0

  const obj = {};
  colors.forEach((a, i) => {
    obj[a] = Math.floor(count[i] / 2); //you can use ceil if u want to count single left over as 1
  })

  return obj;

}



console.log(sockMerchant(stok))
```

Comment: thanks your answer is very helpful, but how to use object [obj] if I declare 
const colors = stock.map(e=> e == 1 ? e = "blue" :
                                 e == 3 ? e = "green" :
                                 e == 5 ? e = "black" :
                                 e == 8 ? e = "red" : "undefined" )

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

You can read about mapping in object at this link. Here u may get more info